# Cordova error: Requirements check failed for JDK 1.8 or greater -- am using java 9

Tags: java, cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap

While trying to build an android apk with cordova, I get the following error:

> Error: Requirements check failed for JDK 1.8 or greater

[image]

What can I do to resolve this error?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Uninstall jdk 9 and then install jdk 8.
Maybe cordova is not able to detect jdk**9**>jdk**1.8**

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem

Comment: Thank you, Dear @Bilash.

Comment: this is probably due to a bug in jdk9 which somehow doesn't report build numbers maybe as per my experience , i did the same and gone ahead

Comment: I'd say it's more a bug in cordova. By now, it should be able to identify the version properly, yet this bug is still present

Comment: This worked for me too