# Cordova cli doesn't detect JDK

Tags: cordova, cordova-cli

When I run the following command:

```
ionic cordova build android --prod --release
```

I get an error:

```
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\java\jdk-9.0.1
Error: Requirements check failed for JDK 1.8 or greater

[ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova build android --release (exit code 1).
```

Why does it fail? My jdk version is 9.0.1, which is definitely greater than 1.8.

I saw the following suggestions on the Internet:
1) Uninstall older JDK versions - but I don't have an older version
2) Update some environment variables - didn't help either

I'm running Windows 10 (64-bit).

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Someone posted an answer here, I tested it, and it worked. When I returned in order to accept it, the answer turned out to be deleted for some reason.

Anyway, the answer is:

1) Configure the ANDROID_HOME environment variable based on the location of the Android SDK.
2) Add ANDROID_HOME/tools, and ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools to your PATH.

Answer (score 0):

Configuring `ANDROID_HOME` haven't worked for me.

The solution for my problem was given by Bilash in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46379965):
Uninstall JDK 9 and install JDK 8.